# creating android initial information pages if user opens it first time else opening signup or login Activity

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am new new in Android and trying to create an app which opens with splash screen and then shows 3-4 initial app info Activities/fragments and in the last Activity/fragment there should be a signup button or text. Then another splash screen should display and user should be directly taken to the registration page.

Can you suggest me any link or tutorial similar to my requirements?

For splash screen in AndroidManifest.xml I have put it for launcher and it is working fine, after splash screen it opens the MainActivity where using  FragmentPagerAdapter I am creating the 3 swipable info fragements.

MainActivity.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

myPageAdapter.java

```
public class ma_pager_adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ma_pager_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tab1 t1 = new tab1();
                return t1;
            case 1:
                tab2 t2 = new tab2();
                return t2;
            case 2:
                tab3 t3 = new tab3();
                return t3;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }//set the number of tabs
```

One of the fragement is shown below along with the code where I am trying to open a new activity but it is not working. Basically I am failing to open a new Activity from this Fragement.

Tab3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#117edd">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="GET STARTED"
        android:id="@+id/goToSignUPPage"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#f46821"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="clickToOpenSignUpPage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Tab3.java

```
public class tab3 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    public void clickToOpenSignUpPage(View view) {
        System.out.print("HERE");

        if(view.getId()==R.id.goToSignUPPage){
            /*Intent i = new Intent(tab3.this,SignUpPage.class);*/
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),SignUpPage.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);
//            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are asking for many things did you start with android turorials? Also you have to check shared preference

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared prefrences for this .Change value once its gone through that page,So it will open once only, refer this [Shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

What i do for this is using shared prefs.

Add this to your main activty:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("YOUR APP  NAME", 0);
boolean bool = settings.getBoolean("CHOOSE A SAVE NAME", false);
```

What this does is it looks if the save name is saved and if it doesn't exist it returns valse

so what you can do now is:

```
if (bool == false){
//open the page you want
}
```

And to put the bool on true you can do this:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("APPNAME", 0);
//makes it editable
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
//puts the bool on true
editor.putBoolean("SAME SAVE NAME", true);
//saves it
editor.commit();
```

More info can be found here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: I guess its because of variables naming convention (bool instead of some meaningful name) and also you should not use commit(), but use apply() which is asynchronous

Comment: @Creck He can change that name also commit() thats what de page said we have to use under "Write to Shared Preferences" but thanks for your comment i will give it a valid name next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME = "is_first_time";
```

and

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

if (prefs.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME, true)) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME, false).commit();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not first time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can use 'apply() added in API Level 9' instead of 'commit() added in API Level 1'